# Create ZIP/RAR files with only last modified files between date (WINDOWS)

Tags: php, windows, zip, rar

I have modified some php code files which are part of a project that lives in a directory with subdirectories. Now I'd like to send a zip file which contains only the files that were modified last to another person. Like:

/c/index.php

/c/out/inc_out.php

/sales.php

Is there an easy way to select a date range and create a ZIP/RAR archive with the latest modified files? I'm on Windows.

Comment: Use `filemtime` to get the last modified time.

Comment: Ok, but how to zip files and folder structure?

Comment: Oh, that's really your question? There's a PHP library for that. Use it.

Answer (score 8):

Why using a script for this task? **WinRAR** supports such tasks directly.

- Start **WinRAR**.
- Navigate to the folder with the modified files to compress into a ZIP or RAR archive file.
- Click on command **Add**.
- Select the tab **Time**.
- On list item **Include files** select either *Newer than* or *Modified after*.
- Enter the appropriate time values according to the selected option.
- Click on button **OK**.

**WinRAR** adds to the archive now only files with a last modification time according to the specified time values.

See help of **WinRAR** or file **Rar.txt** in program files folder of **WinRAR** if creating the ZIP/RAR archive file should be done from command line. There are explained the command line options `-ta<date>` (modified after) and `-tn<time>` (newer than).

Comment: Dam this is a great answer, now to be able to do this via a command prompt! `-tn` FTW :) thanks